# Tastypie detail_uri_name with forignkey's attribute

Tags: python, mysql, django, api, tastypie

I have a extended the `User` Django class with my own user class in django:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='my_user')
     theme = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     tags = TaggableManager()
```

And a corresponding tastypie resource, that I want to use `detail_uri_name` with the username from the Django user class. Although, I do not know how.

```
class MyUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        detail_uri_name = 'user_username'# ????
```

Error I have is: `'MyUser' object has no attribute 'user__username'`

How do I access the `username` from `MyUser` as an attribute?

The line is:

```
 detail_uri_name = 'user_username'# ????
```

From the shell I can do `MyUser.objects.all()[0].user.username` to get the username of the associated django class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use other class attribute as a `detail_uri_name`.

But, in theory:

```
class MyUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all().select_related('user')
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        detail_uri_name = 'user__username'

    def get_bundle_detail_data(self, bundle):
        attrs = self._meta.detail_uri_name.split('__')
        return getattr(getattr(bundle.obj, attrs[0]), attrs[1])
```

Comment: This seems like a great idea, and I read the docs and it should work. But when I overload `get_bundle_detail_data` it does not actually get called. I think I am doing something wrong somewhere else, but if you have any insight I would appreciate it.